# Выровнять блоки div по высоте

Tags: html, css

имеется html:

```
<div class="class">
    <div class="green_fon">
        привет андрей
        <div class="blue_fon">внутри андр</div>
    </div>
    <div class="green_fon2">
        привет паша
    </div>
</div>
```

так же есть css:

```
.green_fon{ /* div */
  display: inline-block;
  background: #7def72;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-top: 5px solid #001f3f;

  margin-left: 1;
  margin-right: 1;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;

  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;

}
.blue_fon{ /* div */
  display: inline-block;
  background: #48cae2;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-top: 5px solid #001f3f;

  margin-left: 1;
  margin-right: 1;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;

  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.green_fon2{ /* div */
  display: inline-block;
  background: #7def72;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-top: 5px solid #001f3f;

  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;

  margin-left: 1;
  margin-right: 1;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;

}
.class{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

[image: картинка]

Не могу сделать так, чтобы эти два 'зеленых' были одинаковый высоты и выровнены. желательно добиться так, чтобы они были одного класса, но это не принципиально. снаружи висит вспомогательный div, я пробовал растянуть divы внутри до его границ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйся flexbox'ом,

```
.class{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
```

после этого элементы станут в одну линию. затем..
удалите margin везде, у вас будет что-то типа

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLJpw.png
```

затем напишите в хтмл вместо class="green_fon"  => class="green_fon first"
а второй класс  class="green_fon2" станет таким => class="green_fon"
в css добавьте:

```
.first{
display: flex;
justify-content: start-end;
margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Например, так

Comment: Cпасибо огромное, все работает.